# ASP.NET reflection safety

Tags: asp.net, decompiling

Sorry if this is redundant but did some googling and am not quite satisfied I understand things.

I know a .NET binary can be decompiled pretty easily, but I can't figure out exactly how safe an ASP.NET site is (assuming no leaked files).

1. Can any part of a codebehind be interpretted without a DLL?
2. If you don't precompile, is there anything besides the codefiles themselves that could expose your code?
3. Can a snooper see which installed/referenced libraries are in a web app?

Thanks all!

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by "safe" here.  If someone has access to your web server, then you can't really trust anything.

Comment: Well users have access to it obviously. Otherwise I'm assuming no major breaches or  leaked files or XSS. I'm just not very familiar with decompiling or black hat methodologies.

Comment: Why is it obvious that other users have access to the web sites source files?  They shouldn't.  The point is, if you don't have security to the website, it doesn't matter about anything else, as there are an astronomical number of things an attacker could do.

Comment: Not access to the site files, access to the application. Let's say a site with a database connection stored in the web config that uses tokenized auth before allowing users to upload images and interact with the database, but all through the c# codebehinds and classes.

Comment: As long as you are using custom error pages you should be ok.  You need custom error pages so the user can't stumble into a stack trace, but other than that you are generally safe.  Especially if you are following best practices with tokenized auth (like Identity Server) etc.

Comment: @DevinD - If the users don't have access to the site files, then you don't have to worry about anyone disassembling or figuring out things, unless those things are visible through the HTML (for instance, if you link to jQuery files, they will know you're using jQuery).  ASP.net websites automatically disallow the downloading of code files and configuration files (.cs, .vb, .config, etc...) so there isn't any way if your site is properly configured for anyone to download those files.  Other files you might have, might need to be stored in other disallowed folders, like App_Data or App_Code

Comment: Thanks a lot both of you, this is the info I was looking for!

Sounds like the only non-default config for a fresh web app on a fresh server would be the error config? I'd be happy to mark an answer if someone wants to submit a paraphrase of the salient points.

I do have some ashx files which is a different flow, but I assume these are protected as codefiles.